# Internet not working settings gui missing

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

Woke up to having no WiFi or settings option in ububtu 18.04. Tried connecting router directly to laptop, didn't help.

My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig gives

[image]

```
lspci -vkm | grep -i wireless
```

gives

```
Device: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

**EDIT**: My WIFI settints **do not work**. I no longer have a Settings icon. I **can't open settings**. I can't see wifi settings when right clicking on the topmost panel near the charge indicator. It all disappeared.
save

**EDIT**: I can't comment here (old browser). `gnome-control-center wifi` gives command not found error. Super key + search for settings gives no result

**EDIT**:

I loged out. Under the cogwheel there are these options:

```
i3
i3 (with debug log)
Ubuntu <--- selected
Ubuntu on Wayland
```

I can't comment because I have to use an old PC with win xp to have Internet.

and

```
rfkill
```

command gives output:

```
0 wlan phy0 ublocked unblocked
```

**EDIT1**:
Yes, I've rebooted several times. And it's unfortunatelly the only user...

**EDIT2**:

I tried creating a new user:

```
sudo useradd -m cooltest
sudo passwd cooltest
reboot
```

and then logging in as `cooltest` but

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

still give `network is unreachable` error and I can't access Internet

**EDIT3**: Some other commands I've run:

[image]

Another command I've run:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT4**: Result of another commands checking for three interfaces' statuses:

[image]

more pictures of the output of the third command:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipP5p.jpg

Comment: What if you hit the Super key and type "settings"?

Comment: In `terminal` type `gnome-control-center wifi`.

Comment: Log out. Get to the login screen. Enter/select your username. Hit the cogwheel icon. Tell me what you see, and what's selected. Is this Ubuntu 18.04, or something else besides Ubuntu? Why can't you comment here?

Comment: Have you rebooted? Do you have another user account on this computer that you can log into and see if it has the same problem?

Comment: Temporarily create a new user called "Guest", or "Testing", then log out of your current account, and into the new account, and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: I forget that you can't send comments. Sorry. When you created the cooltest account, never mind that the ping didn't work... did the Wi-Fi Settings panel reappear? Do you have the opportunity to connect via ethernet? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB... if you do, try and boot to it, and see if it works there.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Still no internet. I found a way to add comments - winxp's firefox. And the WIFI panel never appears - on neither of the accounts. Ethernet as in wired connection? I tried connecting an internet wire from computer to router, but it didn't work either

Comment: I'll check out the USB option

Comment: Do you see anything wrong in the console output that I've put in post?

Comment: Time to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema What about the output makes you think it's unsalvageable? ; (

Comment: Because some part of the OS is broken, and we could spend a lot of time trying to figure out why at this point, and reinstalling would be the fastest and most complete resolution. When you reinstall, uncheck the "Format" box, and it'll leave your /home alone.